# Why I'm getting unexpected EOF for my cron job?

Tags: shell, cron

I am receiving an error with my Cron job. The error I keep getting is:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Here is my code:

```
mysqldump -u database_user -p']T%zw51' database > /home/site/public_html/Secure/Cron/Database_Backup/database_backup.sql
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You may need to escape the `%` with a `\`. 
`%` is a special character to the crontab, which gets translated to a newline, so your code was probably becoming

```
 -p']T
 zw51'
```

Try:

```
 -p']T\%zw51'
```

Comment: Didn't get this error in Fedora 25 but had it on CentOS 7.

Comment: Very nicely spotted. Also extremely likely to happen if using a formatted date for a var, ie `$(date +\%d-\%b-\%Y)`