# crontab is not executing due unexpected EOF

Tags: cron

I scheduled some jobs in crontab. They are not even running. I also checked with logs along with schedules log file is not even created.

I am getting some EOF error. I think i made some changes in /etc/crontab

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
```

my corntab

```
 35 04 * * * cd /home/ec2-user/cerberus/src/automation_scripts/act/ && sh active.sh >> /home/ec2-user/cerberus/logs/active/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"` 2>&1
```

[image: ERROR]

Comment: The message says that there is a missing closing backtick, but the crontab you show has no backticks. Was it a user crontab, and not the system crontab at `/etc/crontab`?

Comment: So you are implying that I have missed some bacticks in scheduled jobs.

Comment: I'm saying that you're not showing us the crontab that causes the problem and we can't help you unless you do - but yes, the error message says that the file ended while parsing a backtick enclosed string.

Comment: 35 04 * * * cd /home/ec2-user/cerberus/src/automation_scripts/act/ && sh active.sh >> /home/ec2-user/cerberus/logs/active/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"` 2>&1

Comment: i found that i missed slash in the date. so it has to be `date "+\%Y-\%m-\%d"`

Comment: You have to escape the percent signs with `\%`, or they are interpreted as marking the beginning of input. The [cron tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) has that in its debug section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I'm getting unexpected EOF for my cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468733/why-im-getting-unexpected-eof-for-my-cron-job)